# how to test md5 in c# in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, md5

just want to ask if anyone know how to test this md5 in visual studio?

this is my md5

```
   using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Example
{
    // Hash an input string and return the hash as
    // a 32 character hexadecimal string.
    static string getMd5Hash(string input)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string.
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    // Verify a hash against a string.
    static bool verifyMd5Hash(string input, string hash)
    {
        // Hash the input.
        string hashOfInput = getMd5Hash(input);

        // Create a StringComparer an compare the hashes.
        StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        if (0 == comparer.Compare(hashOfInput, hash))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    static void Main()
    {
        string source = "Hello World!";

        string hash = getMd5Hash(source);

        Console.WriteLine("The MD5 hash of " + source + " is: " + hash + ".");

        Console.WriteLine("Verifying the hash...");

        if (verifyMd5Hash(source, hash))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The hashes are the same.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The hashes are not same.");
        }

    }
}
// This code example produces the following output:
//
// The MD5 hash of Hello World! is: ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c.
// Verifying the hash...
// The hashes are the same.
```

Comment: This tests if `ComputeHash(x) == ComputeHash(x)`, in a round-about way. The intent is ... vague.

Comment: Do you mean you actually want to test the value, or you want to know how to run this code in Visual Studio? This code is taken from MSDN, so it's probably quite robust.

Answer (score 3):

The RFC provides a handful of [test vectors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321#appendix-A.5) you can test against:

```
MD5 ("") = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 ("a") = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
MD5 ("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
MD5 ("message digest") = f96b697d7cb7938d525a2f31aaf161d0
MD5 ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b
MD5 ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") =
d174ab98d277d9f5a5611c2c9f419d9f
MD5 ("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
78901234567890") = 57edf4a22be3c955ac49da2e2107b67a
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio...new Console Application....paste that code (replacing the existing page) and press CTRL + F5. By pressing CTRL + F5, the console window will remain open.

Of course, copy and pasting the code will only get you so far in learning how it works and what it's doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

The md5 class gives you a 16 byte long hash , if your trying to view this hash as a string you need to use the System.Text.Encoding namespace and covert the text over to a string value. As far as testing the MD5 , if it's not 16 bytes long, id say the function failed.